# How to replace the default TextOverflow.ellipsis (which is ... ) to a specify string

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code

```
   Text(
            'Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Text ',
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style:  TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 13)
        )
```

by default it display (...) if it overflow

question : How to replace the (...) to (www) for example ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to solve this issues
this package its easy to use and solve this problem
https://pub.dev/packages/readmore

Comment: thanks but this is out my question

Comment: How does it not answer your question?